# SQL query over three tables returning an aggregate answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q: For each customer list the CustomerID and total number of orders placed.

I believe that I can execute this query with these three tables

```
Customer_T                              Order_T                  OrderLine_T
+------+------+------+-  +---------+-----------+-------+   +---------+-----------------+
|CustID| CNAME | Addr |  | OrderID | OrderDate |CustID |   |OrderID  | OrderedQuantity |
+------+------+------+   +-------+----+--------+-------+   +---------+-----------------+
```

I tried several queries, this is my latest iteration which returns the error Customer_T.CustomerID is invalid because it is not contained in an aggregate function or group by clause.

```
SELECT 
   Customer_T.CustomerID, Order_T.OrderID
FROM 
   Customer_T, Order_T, OrderLine_T
WHERE 
   Order_T.CustomerID=Customer_T.CustomerID
   AND Order_T.OrderID=OrderLine_T.OrderID
ORDER BY 
   COUNT(OrderLine_T.OrderedQuantity)
```

I am not sure where to go here... should i be using a Join operator or something?

EDIT: I should mention that the need to pull additional CustID from the Customer_T table is b/c there are customers who have not purchased anything and are not included in the order table (for EACH customer).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes you should try using JOIN's. Its pretty easier to achieve the result using joins in your case.

Comment: Ok I haven't gotten to joins yet.  I'm not quite sure how to think about a query like this..  Would someone offer up some psuedocode?

Comment: @user3643053 So how far did you get in doing any SQL? Joins is like "I am a cook, I jsut have not gotten towards frying anything ever yet". I.e. chapter 2 or 3 of any introduction to sql.

Comment: "I haven't gotten to joins yet." **nonsense! you already have joins!** it's just a different (and better) syntax. Start by not using commas in the FROM clause this will force you down the correct path.

Comment: **"it is not returning customer ids that have 0 purchases"** this is a requirement that you have failed to mention in the question. If it is a requirement it should be in the question not in some comment half way down the page.

Comment: @Used_By_Already You're right, that was an important point that I forgot to include.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For each customer list the CustomerID and total number of orders placed**

This only requires 2 tables (customers and orders)

```
SELECT
      Customer_T.CustomerID
    , COUNT(Order_T.OrderID) orders_per_customer
FROM Customer_T
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_T ON Customer_T.CustomerID = Order_T.CustomerID
GROUP BY
      Customer_T.CustomerID
ORDER BY
      Customer_T.CustomerID
;
```

Note the use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, this join type allows all records in Customer_T to be returned even if they have not placed an order. I recommend you visit [here for a visual representation of SQL joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

You could add the third table for additional information perhaps, but you would need to take care that you don't exaggerate the number of orders because the line items per order implies a one to many relationship (many line items for a single order). You could do this by introducing `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
SELECT
      Customer_T.CNAME
    , Customer_T.CustomerID
    , COUNT(DISTINCT Order_T.OrderID)  orders_per_customer
    , SUM(OrderLine_T.OrderedQuantity) sum_of_quantity
FROM Customer_T
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_T ON Customer_T.CustomerID = Order_T.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderLine_T ON  Order_T.OrderID = OrderLine_T.OrderID
GROUP BY
      Customer_T.CNAME
    , Customer_T.CustomerID
ORDER BY
      Customer_T.CNAME
    , Customer_T.CustomerID
;
```

Note the sum of quantity isn't a very meaningful metric, it's there merely as a demonstration of approach.

Answer (score 0):

May this would help you get right answer.

```
SELECT ord.CustID, count(ord.CustID) AS OrderCount, cust.CNAMR
FROM Customer_T cust JOIN Order_T ord
    ON ( ord.CustomerID=cust.CustomerID)
    JOIN  OrderLine_T ordLine
    ON ( ord.OrderID=ordLine.OrderID)
GROUP BY ord.CustID ORDER BY OrderCount Desc
```

but it would be trickier to get the order quantity here.

Comment: That doesn't quite return the right answer, but, its a good starting point.  Am I correct in assuming that in Customer_T cust, cust is an alias?

Comment: Ya i guess i have to remove group by and reframe a bit. yes cust is an alias.

Comment: Would you try using a left or right join to solve the same for those customers who have 0 orders?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need.

```
SELECT C.CustID, COUNT(OL.OrderedQuantity) 
FROM Customer_T C 
   JOIN Order_T O ON(O.OrderID=C.CustID)
   JOIN OrderLine_T OL ON(O.OrderID = OL.OrderID)
GROUP BY C.CustID
```

Comment: It is close, in line 3 O.OrderID should be O.CustID. And, while i think it is returning the correct values, it is not returning customer ids that have 0 purchases

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to "... list the CustomerID and total number of orders placed" you don't need to join to any other table, all the information is available in the `Order_T` table:

```
SELECT CustID, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Order_T
GROUP BY CustID
```

Should you want to display the customer's name, then you will need to join tables.

Comment: I am sry.  I will edit the post.  There are customers who have not purchased anything hence the need to return their information from the adjacent table also containing customer ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    C.CustID, 
    SUM(CASE O.OrderID WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NumberOfOrdersPlaced
FROM Customer_T C 
    LEFT JOIN Order_T O ON (O.CustID = C.CustID)
GROUP BY C.CustID
```

The above query will return number of orders placed for each customer. If a customer hasn't placed any order yet, then the value of `NumberOfOrdersPlaced` column will be 0.